# Is it necessary to add further protection to an unauthorised style view in Django REST?

Tags: django, https, django-rest-framework, csrf-protection

Assuming that there is HTTPS, the default CSRF protection and anonymous rate throttling in place is it necessary to add further protection to an unauthorised style view (one that does not need user credentials) in Django REST?  For example on a create user view.  I'm thinking along the lines of possibly sending a secret key or an id with a message authentication code, from the client.

**Update**:
This question is not really specific to REST APIs but could apply to any web based system with a register user type function.